# Implementing the Android Image Cropper errors

Tags: java, android

i am very new to android its really for to figure out the solution at starting stage with out clear way. I am trying to implement the Image Cropper library. This was the library https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper

I found some errors when implementing and doubts where to put the code.

I have added this code in the main activity in onCreate method, I am not sure it's correct way to do

```
// start picker to get image for cropping and then use the image in cropping 
activity
CropImage.activity()
  .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
  .start(this);

// start cropping activity for pre-acquired image saved on the device
CropImage.activity(imageUri)
 .start(this);

// for fragment (DO NOT use `getActivity()`)
CropImage.activity()
  .start(getContext(), this);
```

shows error in getContext(),this

```
CropImage.activity()
     .start(getContext(), this);
```

It shows error in imageUri

```
CropImage.activity(imageUri) //shows me error for imageUri and asked to create a local variable or parameter
  .start(this);
```

I directly pasted the method code in the class activity

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
    CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
      Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
    } else if (resultCode ==             CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
      Exception error = result.getError();
    }
  }
}
```

I have no idea where to implement this stuff

3.Set image to crop

```
cropImageView.setImageUriAsync(uri);
// or (prefer using uri for performance and better user experience)
cropImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

4.Get cropped image

```
// subscribe to async event using 
cropImageView.setOnCropImageCompleteListener(listener)
cropImageView.getCroppedImageAsync();
// or
Bitmap cropped = cropImageView.getCroppedImage();
```

and I have understand cropped object holds the final cropped image.

Please help me to figure out the solution. Thank you hope i find the solution.